# How to redirect subdomain to subfolder in IIS6?

Tags: iis-6, redirect

i want to do a redirect from sub.domain.com to domain.com/sub

How to do it in IIS6? My server is Windows Server 2003, using IIS6

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup a site in IIS for your subdomain.
2. Open the properties ofthe site, go to the Home Directorytab
3. Change the option for "Content for this source should come from" to be "A Redirection to a URL"
4. Supply the full URL of the site you want to redirect to - http://domain.com/folder.

Comment: Tried.. it does not work.. Should I restart server??

Comment: What did you put as the Redirect URL? I've just realised my answer was a bit vauge, see update to part 4

Comment: I put this: http://www.domain.com/sub/

Nothing more or less than that. But it seems like does not work. Well, should I write or call to my ISP provider?

Comment: Sorry, not ISP provider, its the web hosting company that host my website

Comment: Does it do anything?